# Changing special characters into space

Tags: bash, character, space

I have a variable which contains several special characters.  Now I want to change these into space
If I do it one by one, the change goes fine
e.g. txt=$(printf "$txt" | sed 's/\xE2/ /g')

Now to change them all at once I inserted all special characters into a file like this :
\xE1
\xE2
\xC3
...

If I want to change this by doing this nothing happens :
while IFS=: read -r special
do
txt=$(printf "txt" | sed 's/$special/ /g')
done <"/home/u555/specialchar.txt"

What is wrong with this loop ?

Comment: To expand the variable special, you will need to put the sed statement in double and not single quotes and so ... "s/$special/ /g"

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables. Sed doesn't expand variables.

Comment: assuming the patterns could change over time (ie, don't want to hardcode the patterns into your solution) take a look at this [sed solution](https://superuser.com/a/719118) that appears to be similar to what you're trying to do; if this doesn't work for you then please update the question with the original `txt=...` statement, the contents of your pattern file (eg, `cat specialchar.txt`), and the expected value of `txt` once all replacements have been successfully performed

Comment: Are you sure this work with \xE2 ?

Answer (score 2):

`sed` (or any other external utility or a loop) is not needed for this job. You can use builtin `bash` parameter expansions:

```
var=${var//[$'\xe1\xe2\xc3']/ }
```

will do the job at once.

---

**Update** after the comment *"But what if you need to change a lot of special characters (approx 50) I want to keep them in a file, so if I add to add one I don't need to change the program, only the file"*

One method is to define a variable, say, `spchars`, as `spchars=$'\xe1\xe2\xc3'` within a file named, say, `special_characters` and `source` that file into your script:

```
. special_characters
var=${var//[$spchars]/ }
```

then you won't need to modify your script, only the parameter `spchars` in the file `special_characters`.

Comment: Ok, this works fine if you only got 3 special characters in hexadecimal
But what if you need to change a lot of special characters (approx 50)
I want to keep them in a file, so if I add to add one I don't need to change the program, only the file

Comment: @William You can read the updated answer.